# Length of a linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct A like the following:

```
struct A 
            {
            int v; 
            double weight;
            A* next;
            A(int x, double w, A* t){
                v=x;
                next = t;
                weight = w;
            }

        };
```

I am also saving these linked lists in a vector in the following manner:

```
typedef A* link; 
        vector<link>adj;
```

Now, I would like to find the length of the linked list for adj[i]. I know that it is like traversing the linked list and incrementing a count to get the length of the linked list. For some reason I am not getting what I want. I was wondering, if someone could give me some pointers. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying?  This may be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238430/how-can-i-discover-the-size-length-of-a-stdvector)

Comment: Use `std::list` (or perhaps `std::vector`) for your "list".

Comment: "For some reason I am not getting what I want" is not a meaningful description of the problem. Show your counting code and explain what you think is wrong with the result.

Comment: "wondering, if someone could give me some pointers" - 0x36700400, 0x4520000C... more seriously, the idea of a linked list is to let the nodes be linked between arbitrary memory addresses, so you can quickly "snip" nodes out or add them in without moving other elements' data around in memory.  A `vector` - on the other hand - is contiguous.  So, I'm not sure why you're mixing them.  You'd normally want one `A*` to the head of your list - `nullptr` if the list is empty, otherwise `head->next` should point to the next element etc..  Length is how long you can follow that linkage before `nullptr`.

Comment: Perhaps a running total?

Answer (score 1):

something like,

```
int count = 0;
link* node = adj[i];

while(node != 0) {
    node = node->next;
    count ++;
}
```